# how to store data in Temp Table from EXECUTE(@QUERY) where EXECUTE(@QUERY) Returns the Dynamic Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
EXECUTE(@QUERY)
```

1. It Returns the Dynamic columns
2. If i want to store data in Temporary table then i have to declare temp table first with columns and datatypes. but i dont know how many columns returns by EXECUTE(@QUERY).

so how to save dynamic output from EXECUTE(@QUERY) into temp table.

Comment: Use openrowset http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table

Comment: its Totally diffrent.... in my case the columns are dynamic so how can i ?..

Comment: firstly you understand the question and then give answer...

Comment: I understand question and already give answer with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `global temp table` and `select create` statements in `sql server`

```
declare @QUERY nvarchar(500)
set @QUERY = 'select c1, c2, c3 from test_table'

declare @create_sql nvarchar(500)
set @create_sql = 'select * into ##temp_tbl from ('+ @QUERY + ') as x'
EXEC sp_executesql @create_sql

select * from ##temp_tbl
```

Here `select * into ##temp_tbl` will create `##temp table`.

Comment: It will not work if @Query is complicated. For example, if it has IF, SET, WHILE clauses or uses CTE or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution with OpenRowSet. You only have to put all your work with temp table in dynamic sql (or you can use global temp table)

```
declare @Query nvarchar(max)
set @Query = 
'
select 1 as FirstColumn, ''Hello'' as SecondColumn, GetDate() as ThirdColumn
union
select 2 as FirstColumn, ''world'' as SecondColumn, GetDate() as ThirdColumn
'

execute(@Query)

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 

'
select * into #MyTempTable 
from OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=yes;'', '''+ Replace(@Query, '''', '''''') +''')

select * from #MyTempTable
'

exec sp_executeSQL @sql

-- global table example
set @sql = 

'
select * into ##MyTempTableGlobal 
from OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=yes;'', '''+ Replace(@Query, '''', '''''') +''')
'

exec sp_executeSQL @sql

select * from ##MyTempTableGlobal
```